# django - Foreign key models, view that inherts 3 models deep

Tags: python, django

Apologies for the title if there is proper terminology for what im trying to achieve, im just not sure the name of what i want.

i have 3 models for example:

```
Sites
-name 

Site Circuits
-- circuit_name
-- foreignKey_sites

Site Circuit files
--- circuit_filename
--- foreignkey_siteCircuits
```

so in my view i want to show all the circuit files associated with sites, but circuit files does not have a shared key with sites, it has one with circuit files...

so far i have the sites and i have the circuits by getting the ID of each, but am unsure of how i now get those circuit files without a relationship?

views.py

```
def showroom_detail(request, showroom_id):
    modelSite = get_object_or_404(SiteData, pk=showroom_id)
    modelCircuits = CircuitInfoData.objects.filter(Site_Data=showroom_id)
    modelCircuitFiles = CircuitInfoData.objects.filter(???)

    return render(request, 'service/site_detail.html', {
        'Showroom': modelShowroom,
        'Circuits': modelCircuits,
        'CircuitFiles': modelCircuitFiles,
    })
```

Comment: How many database records are we talking about? I generally use a "bad" method of checking by searching all parent records. I believe there is another way, so I will try to locate it.

Comment: Just to confirm, you need to get all `Site Circuit files` from a specified `Site`?

Comment: @techydesigner yes that is correct, there are not many record, we have around 150 sites, each site has around 5 circuits and each circuit may have 1 or two files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want all files for all curcuits for a particular site, you are looking for

```
Files.objects.filter(circuit__site_id=showroom_id)
```

(exact names depend on what you've named your models and fields)

The double underscore `__` in the query field traverses model relationships